# RegEx lookahead on .*

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a pattern that needs to find the **last** occurrence of string1 unless string2 is found anywhere in the subject, then it needs the **first** occurrence of string1.  In order to solve this I wrote this inefficient negative lookahead.

```
/(.(?!.*?string2))*string1/
```

It takes several seconds to run (prohibitively long on subjects lacking any occurrence of either string).  Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe you just want to split this up into two regexs? `if(findString2){findLastString1} else {findFirstString1}`

Comment: That would be ideal if the situation allowed.

Comment: Does the situation not allow for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the following:

```
/string1(?!.*?string2)/
```

This will match `string1` as long as `string2` is not found later in the string, which I think meets your requirements.

**Edit:** After seeing your update, try the following:

```
/.*?string1(?=.*?string2)|.*string1/
```

Comment: The regex he has already works. He is looking to optimize the speed of it. Is your regex faster?

Comment: @Dgrin91 Clear as blue sky.

Comment: I need it to always capture string1, it's just to distinguish which occurrence.  This will only capture half the time.

Comment: @Dgrin91 my answer continues along the path beset by our OP but I wouldn't call it the best solution.

Comment: @Umbrella Have you tried it?  This will match `string1` in every string that contains `string1` as long as there is at least one occurrence of `string1` after every occurrence of `string2`.  To make it more similar to your current regex you could change it to `/.*?string1(?!.*?string2/`, so that it also matches everything before `string1`.

Comment: For the input `foo-string1-bar-string1` this regex captures both `string`` but OP wants to capture only first one in this case.

Comment: @anubhava The OP's current regex will also capture both `string1`... and if you only want the first match you just make sure you aren't using global matching.

Comment: By error, I inverted my request.  I actually need the first `string1` if `string2` is found.  I need to NOT capture after `string2`, if it is found.

Comment: Anyway, this pattern always captures the first `string1`, without regard for `string2`

Comment: @Umbrella This pattern will only match the second `string1` in the string `string1-string2-string1`.  Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/SSiKHdwGu4

Comment: @Umbrella It would have been nice to put an example of inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Credit to Casimir for showing me how to "allow multiple capture groups with the same name", which makes your solution the best overall.

Answer (score 2):

Ok now, i have understand what you want, a bit long but optimized to be fast:

```
nutria\d.    -> string1
RABBIT       -> string2
```

The pattern *(example in PHP)*:

```
$pattern = <<<LOD
~(?J)               # allow multiple capture groups with the same name

  ### capture the first nutria if RABBIT isn't found before ###
  ^ (?>[^Rn]++|R++(?!ABBIT)|n++(?!utria\d.))* (?<res>nutria\d.) 

  ### try to capture the last nutria without RABBIT until the end ###
  (?>
     (?>
        (?> [^Rn]++ | R++(?!ABBIT) | n++(?!utria\d.) )*
        (?<res>nutria\d.)
     )*                         # repeat as possible to catch the last nutria
     (?> [^R]++ | R++(?!ABBIT) )* $  # the end without RABBIT
  )?   # /!\important/!\  this part is optional, then only the first captured
       # nutria is in the result when RABBIT is found in this part

| # OR

  ### capture the first nutria when RABBIT is found before
  ^(?> [^n]++ | n++(?!utria\d.) )*  (?<res>nutria\d.)

~x
LOD;

$subjects = array( 'groundhog nutria1A beaver nutria1B',
                   'polecat nutria2A badger RABBIT nutria2B',
                   'weasel RABBIT nutria3A nutria3B nutria3C',
                   'vole nutria4A marten nutria4B marmot nutria4C RABBIT');

foreach($subjects as $subject) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match))
        echo '<br/>'.$match['res'];
}
```

The pattern is designed to fail as fast as possible using atomic groups and possessive quantifiers with alternations and thus avoids catastrophic backtracking using the least possible lookaheads (only when a `n` or an `R` is found, and it fails quickly)

Comment: Yes, I can, but I don't always want the last

Comment: @Umbrella: I did not understand your question! Take a look at my edit.

Comment: +1 for "allow multiple capture groups with the same name"  That makes FJ's solution workable.  Unfortunately, I don't always know if "Rabbit" starts with "R".

Comment: @Umbrella: you can easily split the first character of your strings and put them in the pattern with variables

Answer (score 2):

You could also do if/else statements in your regex !

```
(?(?=.*string2).*(string1).*$|^.*?(string1))
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?                      # If
    (?=.*string2)       # Lookahead, if there is string2
    .*(string1).*$      # Then match the last string1
    |                   # Else
    ^.*?(string1)       # Match the first string1
)
```

If `string1` is found, you'll find it in group 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
string1(?!.*?string1)|string1(?=.*?string2)
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/uAjOqaTkYH

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/-APgkX1ZEteFBTrl)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the possessive operator `.*+`, it uses less memory (it doesn't store the entire backtrace of matching cases). It may also run faster because of this.

Comment: Do you mean `/(.(?!.*+?string2))*string1/` or `/(.(?!.*?string2))*+string1/` or `/(.(?!.*+?string2))*+string1/`?

Comment: Actually, one doesn't speed it up, and the other is invalid syntax.

Comment: I said it `may` speed it up due to having to do less operations when finding a match (each extra character in the string is a match for `.*`). But I can't tell if the speedup would be significant.